# Bottom Up reference in Ms Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I'm doing seating arrangement for an exam.
**Sheet1 - A1:A5** (Contains Roll numbers)

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want this in Sheet2 *Bottom up reference from another sheet*
**Sheet2 - A1:15**

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

I did This
1. In Sheet2 A5 `=Sheet1:A1`
2. In Sheet2 A4 `=Sheet1:A2`
3. Dragged up after selecting these two cells.

This is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put following formula to `Sheet2` A1 cell then drag and down

```
=LARGE(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,ROW(1:1))
```

Comment: This solves my problem to an extent. But this works only if roll numbers are in ascending order.

Comment: What if there are words instead of numbers?

Comment: Then use `Indirect()` function like `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & 6-ROW(1:1))` Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: can u please explain what is  `6-ROW(1:1)`

Comment: Yes. `Row(1:1)=1` so `6-1=5` means `Sheet1!A5`. When you drag and down the formula then in cell `A2` formula will be `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & 6-ROW(2:2))` That means `Row(2:2)=2` so `6-2=4` which means `Sheet1!A4`. Hope understand.